# Conditional sum and percentage when item in lists (Sum if and percent if)

Tags: postgresql

I have a list of customers, products they bought and total revenue. I want to return a column that sums revenue for each customer when products = a certain list i.e.

`sum revenue when products in [list] and customers in [list] and call this column revenue_for_large_products`

After that, I want to return another column that finds the percentage of revenue coming from the above column and total i.e.

`revenue_for_large_products divided by total_revenue multiplied by 100`

Can I please get help writing these lines of code?

Thanks

Comment: What is the name of the table that holds your information? Is there more than one table? 
What columns do you want in the output/result? e.g. `| Product | Client | revenue | % of revenue | `  Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The table is named 'revenue.by_customer_by_product'

Comment: I want to output customer_id, revenue_month, revenue from specific products, revenue from all products, percent revenue from specific products.

Comment: I also asked this question which may provide more context on what I'm trying to do https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73328716/creating-lists-and-referring-to-them-in-a-query

Comment: I think you are looking for `sum(revenue) filter (where ....)`?