# Creating lists and referring to them in a query

Tags: sql

I have a table source with columns customer_id, products, total_revenue, revenue_month

I want to do the following:

1. Define a list of specific customers I want to use in my query
2. Define a list of specific products I want to use in my query
3. In the query, return the customers from step 1, revenue_month, their total revenue
   from all products, their total revenue from just the products in
   step 2, percentage of revenue from step 2 products/total revenue

here is my code so far

```
-- this is my attempt at steps 1 and 2, creating a list and adding values
special_customers['1','2','3','4','5']
special_products['a','b','c','d','e']

-- this is my attempt at step 3 
with results as
(select 
tablesource.customer_id,
tablesource.revenue_month,
-- tablesource also has a field named total_revenue, which i am using in the two actions below

-- need a line here that returns a sum of total_revenue for products in the special_products list

-- need a line here that returns a sum of total_revenue for all products
-- need a line here that gives percentage from the above two 
  
from tablesource
where total_revenue != 0
and tablesource.revenue_month >= '2021-08-01'
and customer_id in (customers_with_usage_attribution)


group by
customer_id, revenue_month

order by
customer_id, revenue_month

)

select * from results
```

I'm very new to sql so very sure that a lot of the syntax is wrong but I would appreciate some help.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: I think it's metabase. I think we have data files stored there so I'm referencing them as the data sources. I hope that's what you're asking.

Comment: In the other quetion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73327981/conditional-sum-and-percentage-when-item-in-lists-sum-if-and-percent-if you tag the database as postgresql **PLEASE** find out what database it really is and use a **TAG** with the correct database. This matters to **you** as the solution has to work in **your** environment